# Does this conic have a rational point?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations, rational-points

Consider the conic
$$C = \{X^2+uY^2+vZ^2=0\}\subset\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{Q}(u,v)}$$
over the function field $\mathbb{Q}(u,v)$.

Does $C$ have a $\mathbb{Q}(u,v)$-rational point?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Comment: The informal argument is: if there would be a point over $\mathbb{Q}(u,v)$, then by specializing $u,v$ to arbitrarily chosen rational values, you would get the conclusion that every conic of the form $X^2+u_0Y^2+v_0Z^2=0$ with $u_0,v_0\in \mathbb{Q}$ would have a ($\mathbb{Q}$-)rational point, and therefore that every conic over $\mathbb{Q}$ has a rational point, since every conic can be brought into this form. But this last statement is (of course) known to be false.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is no. If there was, we could assume that $X,Y,Z$ are in $\mathbb Q[u,v]$ and are coprime (since that ring is a UFD). Setting $v=0$ we get $X(u,0)^2+uY(u,0)^2=0$ in $\mathbb Q[u]$, which (for instance by looking at the degrees) forces $X(u,0)=Y(u,0)=0$, meaning $X=vX',Y=vY'$ for some $X',Y'\in\mathbb Q[u,v]$. But looking back at the original equation this implies $v^2\mid vZ^2$, hence $v\mid Z^2$ and $v\mid Z$, contradicting coprimality.

You can generalize this argument greatly - all that was needed in this argument is that $u,v$ are elements of the ring $R=\mathbb Q[u,v]$ such that $-u$ is not a square in the fraction field of $R/v$, that $v\mid Z^2$ implies $v\mid Z$, and that we can always reduce the variables such that not all are divisible by $v$. The last two follow automatically from $v$ being a squarefree element of a UFD, but even that is more than enough.

Comment: I don't understand why your statement is considered proof - if formally you haven't even started solving the equations? For such an equation, it is always possible to choose coefficients so that there are solutions. It's a quadratic equation. Parameterization can always be written.

Comment: @individ I'm not sure what you mean. For a parametrization of a projective quadratic curve you need it to have some rational point in the first place. I prove there isn't one.

Comment: Parametrization can be written without knowing the first rational point.  One of the options is to consider the equivalent Pell equation.  Or simply use the formula to select the necessary coefficients to solve the equation. 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2773097/how-to-find-all-rational-solutions-of-x2-3y2-7/2788381#2788381

Comment: @individ $u$ and $v$ are algebraically independent elements over $\mathbb Q$. Wojowu's proof is perfectly fine.